# trouble using post method with google cloud storage - SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to post object to google cloud storage using the post methord, when submitting the form 
I get 'SignatureDoesNotMatch' error.

I use the following to generate policy and signature:

```
$secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 

$policy_sting = '{"expiration": "2014-06-16T11:11:11Z" , "conditions": [   ["starts-with", "$key", ""],  
  {"acl": "public-read" },   {"bucket": "my-new-bucket"},   {"success_action_redirect": "my-url.html/success" },    
  ] }' ; 


$policy = base64_encode(utf8_encode ($policy_sting)); 
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256",$policy,$secret_key,true));
```

This is my form:

```
<? header('x-goog-project-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); ?>
<? header('x-goog-api-version: 1'); ?>



<form action="http://storage.googleapis.com/my-new-bucket" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" name="key" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read">
<input type="hidden" name="GoogleAccessId" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">


<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="<?=$policy;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?=$signature;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="bucket" value="my-new-bucket">

<input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="---------">

<input name="file" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

How can I solve SignatureDoesNotMatch error?

Comment: Where did you get the policy string from? The documentation shows a very different string to sign: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Construct-the-String

Comment: Hi, I'm using POST method : https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#postobject

policy document : https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#policydocument

Comment: I think you're using HMAC instead of RSA. Any reason you're not using the google-api-php-client library? I think it has the signature routines you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'll rewrte that using openssl_sign ... 

I've tried using google-api-php-client and Google_StorageService object, but I didn't found how to set ACL settings for new objects

Comment: You should be able to set the ACL when creating new objects. Feel free to open a new question to ask for help if you're having trouble.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that.